# How to track users in New Relic using Java EE

Tags: java, soap, ejb-3.0, newrelic

I'm using New Relic to track SOAP based web services. I have all the basics handled.  I need to track by user as well, and that's where I'm stuck.

I've annotated my methods with

```
@Trace(nameTransaction=true,dispatcher=true)
```

I've tried:

```
NewRelic.setUserName(userId);
```

as the second line of code in the method, but I'm still not getting any tracking by username.

I'm not entirely sure if a custom annotation at this point would do it, or not.  What's the best way track by user on a web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may take a support ticket to work out (I'd need to see your dashboard to be sure) but the best method with the Java agent is `NewRelic.addCustomParameter(String key, String value)`

Both that and setUserName will only register for transaction traces on particularly slow transactions, but setUserName only shows up if you've also got data collection working with Real User Monitoring (or RUM).

once you're sending a custom parameter, it will show up on slow transaction traces in your New Relic user interface.

More detail on the nature of and interface for Transaction Traces: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/traces/transaction-traces

Again, to be sure I'd want to check out your dashboard, which I'd prefer to do via ticket at support.newrelic.com